# Determining Detached DOM Trees In Non-Chrome Browsers

Tags: browser, memory-leaks

So with Google Chrome, I am able to take a Heap Snapshot which allows me to see if there are any detached DOM trees (which from my understanding, there shouldn't normally be any).  Well I have an AngularJS application that is show a fair number of these and I am at the point where I am trying to verify whether or not this is a Google Chrome specific issue or an issue with all browsers.

The issue is that I can't find any tools to be able to see if there are detached DOM trees for FireFox, Safari, or IE.  Do any such tools exist?

Comment: Note that it's OK to have a detached DOM in many applications. If you use `ng-if` with angular, you will find many many detached DOM's in your Heap snapshot, since it keeps it detached until it is ready to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the memory profiling tool in IE will help you find the issues. I think it may even be easier than Chrome's tool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess I can download IE 11 and see what it tells me.